# which libraries should I link to build opencv 3.2

Tags: c++, build, cmake, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

Building opencv with contributions using this guide: 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html

instead of cmake gui, i use:

cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=E:\work\opencv2\opencv_contrib/modules E:\work\opencv2\opencv

Error build log:

```
Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unknown .*option'
    Output line: 'cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj]
'
Compilation failed:
    source file: 'E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: '  -fsigned-char'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_7e110.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:02:59.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\cmTC_7e110.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\cmTC_7e110.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue   -fsigned-char E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.cxx

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue   -fsigned-char E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.cxx



cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj]

  src.cxx

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_7e110.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_7e110.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_7e110.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH   /machine:X86 cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\src.obj

  cmTC_7e110.vcxproj -> E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_7e110.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\cmTC_7e110.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_7e110.dir\Debug\cmTC_7e110.tlog\cmTC_7e110.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7e110.vcxproj]



    1 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.46


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unknown .*option'
    Output line: 'cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj]
'
Compilation failed:
    source file: 'E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: '  -fsigned-char'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_7535b.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:02:59.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\cmTC_7535b.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\cmTC_7535b.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   -fsigned-char E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.c

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   -fsigned-char E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.c



cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj]

  src.c

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_7535b.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_7535b.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_7535b.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH   /machine:X86 cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\src.obj

  cmTC_7535b.vcxproj -> E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_7535b.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\cmTC_7535b.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_7535b.dir\Debug\cmTC_7535b.tlog\cmTC_7535b.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fsigned-char' [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_7535b.vcxproj]



    1 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.44


===== END =====

Determining if the function fseeko exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:03:11.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\cmTC_1ca4b.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\cmTC_1ca4b.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=fseeko /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=fseeko /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"



  CheckFunctionExists.c

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_1ca4b.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_1ca4b.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_1ca4b.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH   /machine:X86 cmTC_1ca4b.dir\Debug\CheckFunctionExists.obj

CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fseeko referenced in function _main [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_1ca4b.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fseeko referenced in function _main [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_1ca4b.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1ca4b.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.38



Determining size of off64_t failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_69866.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:03:11.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\cmTC_69866.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\cmTC_69866.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_69866.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c



  OFF64_T.c

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(19): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(20): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(21): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(22): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(23): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(19): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(20): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(21): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(22): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(23): error C2065: 'off64_t': undeclared identifier [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_69866.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    5 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29


E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>


#undef KEY
#if defined(__i386)
# define KEY '_','_','i','3','8','6'
#elif defined(__x86_64)
# define KEY '_','_','x','8','6','_','6','4'
#elif defined(__ppc__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','_','_'
#elif defined(__ppc64__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','6','4','_','_'
#endif

#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
char info_size[] =  {'I', 'N', 'F', 'O', ':', 's','i','z','e','[',
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 1000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 100)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10)%10)),
  ('0' +  (SIZE    % 10)),
  ']',
#ifdef KEY
  ' ','k','e','y','[', KEY, ']',
#endif
  '\0'};

#ifdef __CLASSIC_C__
int main(argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
  int require = 0;
  require += info_size[argc];
  (void)argv;
  return require;
}


Determining if the function jbg_newlen exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:03:13.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\cmTC_c6cb2.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\cmTC_c6cb2.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=jbg_newlen /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=jbg_newlen /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"



  CheckFunctionExists.c

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_c6cb2.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_c6cb2.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_c6cb2.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH   /machine:X86 cmTC_c6cb2.dir\Debug\CheckFunctionExists.obj

CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jbg_newlen referenced in function _main [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj]

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_c6cb2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jbg_newlen referenced in function _main [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj]

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_c6cb2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c6cb2.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.37



Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv2/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 31.05.2017 18:03:18.

Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\cmTC_1a06d.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\cmTC_1a06d.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /MP8 /Od /Ob0 /Oi /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1a06d.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue   /bigobj E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c



  CheckIncludeFile.c

E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [E:\work\opencv2\build2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1a06d.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29
```

which libraries do I miss? 
Do I need to add some path variables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to select the "modules" folder inside the extra contrib folder. Exact error happened to me when I only selected the extra contrib folder.